# Unit testing an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application in VS 2005

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0

Most of the stuff I find about unit testing ASP.NET apps seems to be for VS 2010 / later versions of .NET / Visual studio in general. I can't really find the "Create unit tests" option in Visual studio 2005 at all. Can anyone point me to how I can go about Unit testing a .NET 2.0 app in VS 2005?

Thanks,

Teja.

Comment: The built-in unit testing with Visual Studio 2005 requires the Team System editions. Are you using that? [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx) explains how VS2005 tests work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in unit testing framework of Visual Studio you will need the Visual Studio Team System edition (IIRC Microsoft changed their policy and the unit test framework is available in the Professional Edition of VS2008).

If you don't have it you can simply download [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and enjoy unit testing.